# Can we find $c_n$ to make $X_nc_n \rightarrow 0$ almost surely, even if $EX_n > \infty$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables. Can we find $c_n$ (positive constants) so that $X_nc_n \rightarrow 0$?

It is easy with Markov's equality + Borel Cantelli, with assumptions on expectations, but what if we don't know anything about expectations?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we can always find such a sequence (assuming that each $X_n$ is real-valued with probability $1$).

**Hints:**

1. Show that there exists $c_n>0$ such that $$\mathbb{P}\left(|c_n X_n| \geq \frac{1}{n} \right) \leq \frac{1}{n^2}.$$
2. By Step 1, we have $$\sum_{n \geq 1} \mathbb{P} \left(|c_n X_n| \geq \frac{1}{n} \right) < \infty.$$ Conclude from the Borel-Cantelli lemma that $c_n X_n \to 0$ almost surely.