# $c_n\to\infty$ so that $X_n/c_n\to 0$ a.s.

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

> **Question:** If $X_n$ is any sequence of random variables, there are constants $c_n\to\infty$ so that $X_n/c_n\to 0$ a.s.

I know "$X_n\to 0$ *iff* for all $\epsilon >0,\space P(|X_n|>\epsilon\space \text{i.o.})=0$", and for that I have to use Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

By Chebychev's inequality, for any $\epsilon>0$, $P(|X_n|> |c_n|\epsilon)\leq \dfrac{EX^2_n}{c^2_n\epsilon^2}$. Let, $EX^2_n=O(n^k)$, then I choose $|c_n|=O(n^{\frac{k}{2}+1})$. In that case, $P(|X_n|> |c_n|\epsilon)\leq\dfrac{\delta}{n^2}$, for some positive constant $\delta$.

Since, $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\Big(\Big|\dfrac{X_n}{c_n}\Big|>\epsilon\Big)<\infty$$

then, by Borel-Cantelli Lemma, $P\Big(\Big|\dfrac{X_n}{c_n}\Big|>\epsilon\space\text{i.o.}\Big)=0$

Hence, $X_n/c_n\to 0$ a.s.

Is my argument ok? Thanks for your help.

Note: **i.o.** means *infinitely often*.

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2440688/36150

Comment: In order to apply the Tschebysheff inequality, you need that $X_n$ is twice integrable. This assumption is not mentioned in the problem which you are trying to solve.

Comment: What does "$X_n$ is twice integrable" means? I don't know that term actually.

Comment: It means that $\mathbb{E}(X_n^2)<\infty$ (or, equivalently, $X_n \in L^2(\mathbb{P})$).

Comment: @saz can I do this? : We can find $c_n$ s.t., $P(|X_n|>\delta c_n)\leq\dfrac{1}{n^2}$. Now, summing up to infinity will give a.s. convergence. Now, do I have to find exact $c_n$? (I don't know if their is a way, even though dist. function is non-decreasing) Is this ok?

Comment: Well, that's exactly what I suggested in the answer which I linked above, right? To show the existence of such a constant $c_n$ you have to show (or recall) that $\mathbb{P}(|X_n|>R) \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$.